# Как получить всех предков тегов с атрибутом?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xsl

Как с помощью xslt и xpath из, например, такого файла xml:

```
<a>
    <b1>
        <c1 value="1" />
    </b1>

    <b2>
        <c2 value="2" />
    </b2>

    </b3>
        <c3>
            <d value="3" />
        </c3>
    </b3>
</a>
```

получить полные пути к тегам с атрибутом value (список всех предков), т.е.

a/b1/c1/@value

a/b2/c2/@value

a/b3/c3/d/@value

Количество тегов с атрибутом value и вложенность может быть любой

Comment: Найти все ноды с @value. Для каждой пройтись по оси ancestor и вывести путь. https://stackoverflow.com/q/953197/1016033

Answer (score 1):

```
//*[@value]
```

- `//` любой корень (any root)
- `*` любой тэг (any tagName)
- `@value` имеет атрибут value

Остальные извращения тут - https://sodocumentation.net/xpath/topic/3096/find-nodes-that-have-a-specific-attribute